# Disable 1 step for one time login

Tags: users

Is it possible to disable the page of one time login which can be accessed from the reset user password URL sent to the mail:

> www.example.com/user/reset/1234/1429007410/5H-zpRSsUsNNdiiFMZeaIZVthjO4uJjjrsVJ8Jg75Ys

and send the user directly to logged in edit profile page:

> example.com/user/1234/edit?pass-reset-token=fNWPgVXjnHocvcT3mWxp38vOCuLpz1e5lErOCCDGTe0

so we can make it 1 step instead of 2 steps and consider the user clicked the login button from the page 1 which can be dispensable !?

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution with this module [Simple Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset)